# Can "of yore" be preceded by words other than days or time?

Tags: word-usage

For example, "Where is my wanderlust of yore?"

Does the sentence make sense?

Comment: Yes. That sentence makes sense.

Comment: If you run an [ngram on the phrase *of yore*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20yore%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1946,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22of+yore%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1946,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=10), there are numerous examples of other constructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Yore' has the same root as 'year'.  'Of yore' means 'of years gone by'.  You can talk about 'ships of yore' as well as 'days of yore'.  ('Years of yore' is redundant)

Comment: *Year* comes to us from the Old English *gēr* meaning year.  *Yore*, on the other hand, comes from the Old English *geāra* and similar adverbial forms meaning a long time ago.  They are suspiciously similar, but the *OED* says the latter are of "obscure origin."